# return promise value from controller

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I'm working with Node, Express and Objection.js.
My file structure is:

```
 ->Project Folder
   ->Controllers(folder)
     ->agenciaController.js
   ->Models(folder)
     ->Agencia.js
   ->index.js
```

in my index.js code is:

```
var Knex = require('knex');
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var knexConfig = require('./knexfile');
var Model = require('objection').Model;

var knex = Knex(knexConfig.development);
Model.knex(knex);

var reqAgenciaController = require('./Controllers/agenciaController');
var agenciaController = new reqAgenciaController();
app.get("/agencias", function(req, res) {
    var respuesta = agenciaController.getAgencias();
    console.log("log3: "+respuesta);
});
```

And my agenciaController.js is:

```
var Agencia = require('../Models/Agencia');    
module.exports = agenciaController;    
function agenciaController() {
    this.getAgencias = function() {
        var retValue = "retvalue";
        listaAgencias = [];

        Agencia.query()
            .then(function(agencias) {
                listaAgencias = agencias;
                console.log("log1: "+ listaAgencias);
            });
        console.log("log2: "+listaAgencias);
        return listaAgencias;
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I run the code, I get

```
log2:
log3: undefined
log1: [object Object, object Object].
```

But I need:

```
log1: [object Object, object Object].
log2: [object Object, object Object].
log3: [object Object, object Object].
```

My question is: is it possible to return listaApuestas from the controller to index.js, with the value obtained in the promise?

Comment: You don't uderstand how promises work, investigate [this article](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

agenciaController.getAgencias() should be promosified using the promise library of your choice.

I recommend using [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html).

The trick part is that if a promise reside in another promise you'll need to change your structure a little bit.

Sample agenciaController.js

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

agenciaController = {
    getAgencias: function(callback) {
        this.queryAsync().then(function(respuesta) {
            console.log("log2: "+ respuesta);
            callback(false, respuesta);
        })
    },
    query: function(callback) {
        console.log("log1", {});
        callback(false, { respuesta: "respuesta" })
    }
}

Promise.promisifyAll(agenciaController);

module.exports = agenciaController;
```

Sample app.js

```
var AgenciaController = require('./agenciaController');

agenciaController.getAgenciasAsync().then(function(respuesta) {
    console.log("log3: " + respuesta);
});
```

This will output:

```
log1 {}
log2: [object Object]
log3: [object Object]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help! Finally studying more about promises and following their examples, solved the problem.
Here is the code I use to solve the problem

My agenciaController.js:

```
var Agencia = require('../Models/Agencia');    
module.exports = agenciaController;

function agenciaController() {    
    this.getAgencias = function() {

        return Agencia.query()
            .then(function(agencias) {
                return agencias;            
            })
            .catch(function(){
                console.log("error en la promesa");
            });
    }
}
```

And my index.js:

```
var reqAgenciaController = require('./Controllers/agenciaController');
var agenciaController = new reqAgenciaController();

app.get("/agencias", function(req, res) {
    var misAgencias;
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (agenciaController.getAgencias() === undefined){
            reject("Error al llamar al getAgencias");
        }else {
            resolve(agenciaController.getAgencias());
        }
    });

    promise
    .then( agencias => {
        misAgencias = agencias;
        console.log(misAgencias);
        res.send(misAgencias);      
    })
    .catch(err => console.log("Error: "+err))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fn: async function() {
    var output = '';
    await myPromise()
    .then((data) => {
        output = data;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        output = "Error: " + err;
    });

    return ans;
}
```

Notice how we `await` for a promise to finish, before `fn` returns its value